# $A$-content topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\emptyset\subset A\subset X$. Define
$${\cal T}=\{Y\ ;\ A\subseteq Y\subseteq X \}\cup\{\emptyset\}$$
we know $\cal T$ is a topology on $X$.
I want know more about structure of this topology. but I can't find this example on any books. Please help me to find more about this. In particular I want to find a book written about this example.

Answer (score 1):

If $A= \{p\}$ this example is known as the included point topology (wrt $p \in X$).
Or the particular point topology in Counterexamples in Topology, mirrored [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000009) e.g.

This is a slight generalisation of it.

- $X$ is $T_0$ iff $|A|= 1$ in fact. It will rarely fulfill any higher separation axioms (like complete normality or normality).
- $X$ is hyperconnected (all non-open sets intersect), so in particular connected
- $X$ is not compact if $X\setminus A$ is infinite.
- $X$ is separable as any $\{a\}$ with $a \in A$ is dense.
- $X$ is second countable iff $X \setminus A$ is countable.

Etc etc. All this without a book (don't rely on books, just check the definitions!). This space is so simple, almost all properties that are commonly used are easy to verify or disprove for it.